# Image.reduce vs ImageCollection.reduce

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-api

It is my understanding that `imageCollection.reduce()` takes an image collection -collection of images over time, where at any given time the image is/can-be consist of several bands- and then reduces it by acting in time dimension. In other words, for any given band like `B1`, it does the reduction over the time window from `t_1` to `t_n`, and generates an image which has lost its time dimensionality, but has the same number of bands as original `ImageCollection` object.

And `Image.reduce()` which acts on a single image, single image being an object that is snapshot at a given time-i.e. there is no time dimensionality here to begin with- and then reduces the image, by acting on the band dimensionality. So, output will be like a 2D matrix consisting of just one value per pixel.

What does the sentence below mean at the [Image Reductions documentation page](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_image)?

> The output is also an image with number of bands equal to number of
>   reducer outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. I like to imagine it in a different way. For image collection I think of it as multiple image stacks for each bands and the reducer works in the 3rd dimension which is like you said is time dimensions. In case of image I think of it as simply a stack of bands. So it works out that the reducer works in the 3rd dimension. So like I said, your understanding is correct.

The statement just means that the resulting image has bands corresponding to the reducer output. What I mean by that is, referring to the example on the documentation page, they use `ee.Reducer.max()` which gives one result i.e. the maximum value across bands. So, the resulting image has a single band that is max of the input bands. However, if we use `ee.Reducer.minMax()`, the reducer gives two outputs i.e. min value across bands and max value across bands. Therefore the resulting image will have two bands.